# How to make 2D array from 1D array which contains another arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, reshape

I'd like to make 2D array from array that looks like this:

```py
array([[        nan, -0.2693394 , -0.3823119 , ...,  0.50096547,
        -0.38158651, -0.57082454],
       [        nan,  1.51905538,  1.31479685, ...,  0.50096547,
         0.30133149,  1.53212594],
       [-0.41208069,  1.51905538,  1.31479685, ...,  0.50096547,
        -0.38158651, -0.57082454],
       ...,
       [-0.68149616,  0.32679219,  0.18339102, ...,  0.50096547,
        -0.38158651, -0.57082454],
       [-0.68149616,  0.92292379,  0.18339102, ...,  0.50096547,
        -0.30290932, -0.46014294],
       [-0.68149616,  0.92292379,  0.18339102, ...,  0.50096547,
        -0.38158651, -0.57082454]])
```

As you can see this is 1D array that contains array of data in each row. I tried with reshapes, but I couldn't make it just like I want. I had dataframe with about 1500 rows and 25 columns. I standarized it and received this ugly array.

Comment: How working `np.array(arr.tolist())` ?

Comment: what is the shape of this current structure? it looks like a 2D array already

Comment: also note that if each row doesn't have the same number of columns, numpy will implicitly turn it into an array of lists, so you have to make sure there are MxN entries for a MxN array to be implied from the input